# A mess with Qt/Qwt versions - how to revert to original state?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, ubuntu-14.04, qt-designer, qwt

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit. I obviously made a mess by installing Qt Creator and Qt4 Designer. I've built and installed the Qwt (6.1.0) libraries (widgets) that are visible to Qt4 Designer but not to Qt Creator... I'm pretty sure it is the Qt (qmake) version that made these installations incompatible and messy...

The Qt Creator reports:

> Qt Creator 3.0.1
>
> Based on Qt 5.2.1 (GCC 4.8.2, 64 bit)

The Qt4 Designer reports:

> Version 4.8.6

Both installations were done through synaptic utility. Later on, I've used an online installed from Qt project and installed another (opensource) version of Qt Creator (Based on Qt 5.3.2; GCC 4.6.1, 64 bit).

What I'd like to do is use Qwt widgets in Qt Creator and have a working version of Qt Designer (not it doesn't start; Segmentation fault).

Is there a way to wipe all Qt stuff and begin from scratch? Which directories, profiles, etc. should be erased?

Many thanks.

Comment: when did you built Qwt? using which version

Comment: I think I've tried using both qmake versions. In last case, it is qt4 (4.8.6). But in neither case, the Qt Creator does not see the Qwt widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to work with a Qt creator based on Qt 5.2 and you want to build an application using Qr 4.8.

a) build and install Qwt for Qt 4.8 - like always

b) build and install Qwt for Qt 5.2 ( maybe with enabling QwtDesignerSelfContained in qwtconfig.pri ).

Use qmake from the directory of the Qt version you want to build Qwt for.

Then all that's left to do is tell the creator where to find the plugin, that has been built for Qt 5.2 - f.e. by setting the QT_PLUGIN_PATH.